# Grouping output data with sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to get a flatfile database `filename=iplocationdata` to be regrouped into sections.

This file gets updated frequently and it contains a couple of thousand lines, so I'd like to find a smart solution to script the outputs.

What I get looks like this:

```
NA
10.0.0.0/16
Dallas1
NA
10.1.0.0/16
Houston1
EMEA
10.2.0.0/16
Paris1
EMEA
10.3.0.0/16
London1
APAC
10.4.0.0/16
Hong-Kong1
APAC
10.5.0.0/16
Shanghai1
```

I need **two different outputs**.

The **first one** I solved with this:

```
awk 'NR%3{printf $0" ";next;}1' iplocationdata

NA, 10.0.0.0/16, Dallas1
NA, 10.1.0.0/16, Houston1
EMEA, 10.2.0.0/16, Paris1
EMEA, 10.3.0.0/16, London1
APAC, 10.4.0.0/16, Hong-Kong1
APAC, 10.5.0.0/16, Shanghai1
```

The **second list**, I want looking like this:

```
NA
10.0.0.0/16, Dallas1
10.1.0.0/16, Houston1
EMEA
10.2.0.0/16, Paris1
10.3.0.0/16, London1
APAC
10.4.0.0/16, Hong-Kong1
10.5.0.0/16, Shanghai1
```

This I have not been able to solve. I'd prefer a one liner if possible, does someone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Never do `printf $0`, always do `printf "%s",$0` instead. Imagine the difference if/when `$0` contains `printf` formatting characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added missing `,`

```
$ awk '$1==p{next} NR%3==1{print; p=$1} NR%3==2{printf "%s, ",$0} NR%3==0' s.txt

NA
10.0.0.0/16, Dallas1
10.1.0.0/16, Houston1
EMEA
10.2.0.0/16, Paris1
10.3.0.0/16, London1
APAC
10.4.0.0/16, Hong-Kong1
10.5.0.0/16, Shanghai1
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%3 {
    printf $0", "
    next
} 7' iplocationdata | tee outfile1 | awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=", "
}
$1 != p {
    p=$1
    print $1
}
{
    print $2,$3
}' > outfile2
```

Your original awk script for the first part (with the addition of the comma you showed in your output.

The second awk script uses the first script's output as input and saves the first field whenever it differs from the previously saved field, prints `$1` for those lines and prints `$2,$3` for every line.

Answer (score 0):

some cryptic `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR%6!=4{ORS=(++c%5-3)^2==1?", ":RS; print}' file

NA
10.0.0.0/16, Dallas1
10.1.0.0/16, Houston1
EMEA
10.2.0.0/16, Paris1
10.3.0.0/16, London1
APAC
10.4.0.0/16, Hong-Kong1
10.5.0.0/16, Shanghai1
```

perhaps more readable as

```
$ awk '{c=NR%6} c!=4{ORS=c==2||c==5?", ":RS; print}' file
```